# ngx-bootstrap@3.0.1 with angular 5 giving warning for angular common and core

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ngx-bootstrap

I have installed the ngx-bootstrap as per the getting started documentation
https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/getting-started

https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/development/docs/getting-started/ng-cli.md

Current project I am using angular 5 version, But I am getting below warning

[WARNING] npm WARN ngx-bootstrap@3.0.1 requires a peer of @angular/common@>=6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
[WARNING] npm WARN ngx-bootstrap@3.0.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

Here it is showing the peer dependency as https://david-dm.org/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap?type=peer

How I can resolve the this ? Shall I downgrade the the ngx-bootstrap version ? or with current version can be able to resolve.

Thanks

Comment: Can u just add your package.json file here

Answer (score 2):

You have to use ngx-bootstrap 2.0.2 which supports angular v5.

Demo is also provided: https://ngx-bootstrap-latest.surge.sh/#/